# dynamically changing the script tag source on C# side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-4.0

How can I dynamically change the `<script>` `src` attribute from the `Page_Load`?

When I say dynamic, I really mean that it's the same page `Default.aspx`, but each refresh a different `js` source is referenced.  The logic behind which `js` file to select is of no concern, merely the mechanism to set it.

I tried:

`<script id="script1" runat="server" language="javascript" src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

But `script1` is not available on the `.cs` side.  I know I can change it on the `.aspx` side by using the `<% %>` tags, but I don't want to have my logic embedded like that in my `.aspx`.  There must be a way to do this on the `.cs` side in `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your page load handler you could have something like this

```
string csurl = null;
string csname = "myscript";
if (condition)
{
    csurl = "~/a.js";
}
else    
{  
    csurl = "~/b.js";
}

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(cstype, csname))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
        this.GetType(), 
        csname, 
        ResolveClientUrl(csurl));
}
```

or

```
 string csurl = null;
 if (condition)
 {
     csurl = "a.js";
 }
 else    
 {  
     csurl = "b.js";
 }
 Literal script = new Literal();
 script.Text = string.Format(
     @"<script src=""{0}"" type=""text/javascript""></script>",csurl);
 Page.Header.Controls.Add(script);
```

Comment: i must comment, that even due this works, the OP (not you Cleaudio) is making thing awefully complicated for no apparent reason. Having a '<%=Variable%>' is much much cleaner. oh, and instead of 'if' you could use a 'switch' :)

Answer (score 4):

There's a few ways to do this. One approach is to make a `protected` or `public` method in your codebehind that returns a `string`, which returns the correct URL to your Javascript based on your criteria.  Then, just call that method from your markup, like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="<%=GetJavaScriptUrl() %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This example assumes you call the method in your codebehind `GetJavaScriptUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you have much choice other than to use `<%= %>`.

Unless somebody knows different (if so, please comment, and I will change) using the `runat="server"` attribute on a `<script>` block will mean the block will be *executed* on the server side.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, slightly misunderstood your question.

I thought you were saying you didn't want to use `<% %>` to set the `src` attribute of the `<script>` block. I now understand you meant creating individual `<script>` blocks for each file, being display via logical `<%If x Then%><%Else%><%End If%>` blocks.

As other's have already stated (and I have hinted at), you can set the `src` attribute using `<%=GetSrcPath()%>` and have the logic in the GetSrcPath method in your code-behind.

Comment: Basically, I want to avoid using any `<% %>` stuff is possible.  I'm reviewing Claudio Redi's answer, it seems to be closer on track to the type of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Fair enough @user1169578 - it's an interesting solution. (I'm sure you have your reasons for avoiding `<% %>`, but it's there for a reason, it works) Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the script manager:

E.g.,

```
string jsName = condition ? "a.js" : "b.js";

ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(jsName));
```